# Pub failed to rename directory

Tags: flutter

I am getting following error.
I have given read and write access to folder. Also I have excluded folder from antivirus scanner.

```
Pub failed to rename directory because access was denied.
This may be caused by a virus scanner or having a file
in the directory open in another application.
pub finished with exit code 1
```